# How does OpenCV function cv2.fillpoly() work

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

Can someone please explain me how fill poly works in opencv2 python? I am not able to find much running examples to try out.

What I try gives me exception as

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (p.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0) in fillPoly, file /builddir/
build/BUILD/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp, line 2037
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp:2037: error: 
(-215) p.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0 in function fillPoly.
```

Here is my simple code:

```
mask=np.zeros((4, 3))
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [(1,1),(1,2), (2,1), (2,2)], 255)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means it needs a 32-bit integer.

Modify the code to the following:

```
mask = np.zeros((4, 3))
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, np.array([(1,1),(1,2), (2,1), (2,2)], 'int32'), 255)
```

Comment: Yeah, just figured it out as well. Thank you @JeruLuke